# SQL Server 2000 Stored Procedure : expects parameter , which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I created a stored procedure like this

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_COMP]
    (@comp_seq INT,
     @channel VARCHAR(10),
     @comp_type VARCHAR(10),
     @periode_awal DATETIME,
     @periode_akhir DATETIME,
     @period_type VARCHAR(20),
     @rn_from DATETIME,
     @mode int)
```

and then I execute it:

```
EXEC [SP_COMP] 16, 'A', '', '2017-07-16', '2017-07-31', 'MONTH_END', '2017-07-01', 6
```

But I get this error :

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 3, Procedure SP_COMP, Line 0
>   Procedure 'SP_COMP' expects parameter '@rn_from', which was not supplied

Is there something wrong with my procedure?

Comment: The problem has to be somewhere else in the code. Creating a procedure with exactly the same header you used, I can execute the procedure with the command provided by you without any error. Could you provide the whole code?

Comment: Maybe an invisible char that is wrongly interpreted...

Comment: Try creating datetime variables and use these variables to call the procedure

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s I already made a note of the prefix problem in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem could be with the prefix SP_ you are using.
see this http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix
and this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669(v=sql.105).aspx

Also try creating datetime variables to pass to the procedure.
Also always use a language neutral format for datetime values, see this article
http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

```
declare @periode_awal DATETIME = '20170716'
declare @periode_akhir DATETIME = '20170731'
declare @rn_from DATETIME = '20170701'

EXEC [dbo].[SP_COMP] 16, 'A', '', @periode_awal, @periode_akhir, 'MONTH_END', @rn_from, 6
```

I also do not recommend populating your table with '' values, better use null

**EDIT**
when you alter the procedure and call it in one session, then please add a GO between the 2 statements

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_COMP](
    @comp_seq INT,
    @channel VARCHAR(10),
    @comp_type VARCHAR(10),
    @periode_awal DATETIME,
    @periode_akhir DATETIME,
    @period_type VARCHAR(20),
    @rn_from DATETIME,
    @mode int
)

GO -- always put this after an alter or create statement

declare @periode_awal DATETIME = '20170716'
declare @periode_akhir DATETIME = '20170731'
declare @rn_from DATETIME = '20170701'

EXEC [dbo].[SP_COMP] 16, 'A', '', @periode_awal, @periode_akhir, 'MONTH_END', @rn_from, 6
```